# Drools Rule Units with custom *.drl source

Tags: drools

I've been looking into how to setup Drools Rule Units with a custom file path to my `*.drl`. My application allows multiple "sessions" to be started and stopped independently of one another, and each session is effectively a set of `*.drl` files (which may be coming from S3, disk, in-memory, etc..) and a collection of one or more data streams to feed into the rules.

Rule units look to be a better way of expressing rules in a typesafe way, however, doesn't appear to be a clear way of being able to "inject" a KieFilesystem into it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is [no way to refer to custom files within a .drl file](https://docs.drools.org/8.44.0.Final/drools-docs/drools/language-reference/index.html#con-drl-imports_drl-rules); the only way is by referring to them via their package name, which corresponds to the file structure. Perhaps you could create these file structures on-the-fly, depending on your set of custom .drl files, and inject the generated paths as package/file names. This option is feasible, but it feels too convoluted and error-prone.